# Finding MAX value of raw CSV data for specific column in PHP

Tags: php, csv

Using cURL:

```
 $url = $some_site;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

where the '$output' variable contains the following 7 columns (# of rows will vary):

1,a,6045,6168,6731,6847,522800

2,b,7847,8124,7645,7716,614400

3,c,7288,7633,7150,7442,801800

4,d,5546,5791,5460,5581,554200

5,e,4579,4679,4359,4572,557400

etc ...

As you can see, in the 4th column, the numbers are:

6168
 8124
 7633
 5791
 4679

And the highest number is: 8124

I am trying to figure out how to parse the '$output' variable so I can evaluate all the numbers in the 4th column to determine the high.

I have tried:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $output);
echo max($csv[4]);
```

But nothing is returned

Comment: And what is the value of `$csv`?

Comment: $output ... $output is the raw data pulled from the site. in theory, $csv is supposed to be an array that I can analyze to calculate the MAX value of the 4th column, but what I am doing here returns an empty result.

Comment: I asked about `$csv`, not `$output`

Comment: $csv returns blank; not sure how to convert the $output variable to an array

Comment: `explode` by newline?

Comment: yes, fixed it to "$csv = explode(PHP_EOL,$output));" ... did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you output your `$csv` value you will see that it is array with structure like:

```
...
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => c
        [2] => 7288
        [3] => 7633
        [4] => 7150
        [5] => 7442
        [6] => 801800
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => d
        [2] => 5546
        [3] => 5791
        [4] => 5460
        [5] => 5581
        [6] => 554200
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => e
        [2] => 4579
        [3] => 4679
        [4] => 4359
        [5] => 4572
        [6] => 557400
    )
....
```

So your `$csv[4]` is **not** a list of values from column 4. It's the 5th element of your array. So you need to go further, either with a simple `foreach`:

```
$max = 0;
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    // use index `3` because numeration starts with `0`
    if ($max < $row[3]) {
        $max = $row[3];
    }
}
```

Or with `array_column` (since **php5.5**):

```
// take all values witn index `3` and find max
echo max(array_column($csv, 3));
```

In both cases it is `8124`

Answer (score 0):

It's because str_getcsv not following standards, and from output You have a "broken array"... I suppose that it may look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => a
    [2] => 6045
    [3] => 6168
    [4] => 6731
    [5] => 6847
    [6] => 522800
2
    [7] => b
    [8] => 7847
    [9] => 8124
    [10] => 7645
    [11] => 7716
    [12] => 614400
3
    [13] => c
    [14] => 7288
    [15] => 7633
    [16] => 7150
    [17] => 7442
    [18] => 801800
4
    [19] => d
    [20] => 5546
    [21] => 5791
    [22] => 5460
    [23] => 5581
    [24] => 554200
5
    [25] => e
    [26] => 4579
    [27] => 4679
    [28] => 4359
    [29] => 4572
    [30] => 557400
)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5834d98eda11b1726adc9ef1b7592f9ba32242c

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
// $csv is just a string ... output from Your curl will be same I think
$csv = <<<EOT
1,a,6045,6168,6731,6847,522800
2,b,7847,8124,7645,7716,614400
3,c,7288,7633,7150,7442,801800
4,d,5546,5791,5460,5581,554200
5,e,4579,4679,4359,4572,557400
EOT;

function csv2array($csv) {
    $csv = str_getcsv($csv, PHP_EOL);

    return array_map('str_getcsv', $csv);
}

function findMaxInColumn($array, $column = 3) {
    return max(array_column($array, $column));
}

$parsedCsv = csv2array($csv);
print_r(findMaxInColumn($parsedCsv));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82020f0d85acf8d6b15b5e7fd78a8d1a80618ff2